# Conceptually speaking, management interfaces are used for what?

Tags: magento2, class

For example

`Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductManagementInterface` 
`Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductLinkManagementInterface`

They are used for very specific tasks?

Answer (score 3):

***Management interfaces provide management functions that are not related to repositories.***

[Learn more](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/design-patterns.html)

Comment: I ended up in that page but i guess i did not scrolled down enough lol, thanks.